# Python - Function organisation and general best practices

Tags: python

Just a question about good practice. I have a file that is importing classes and calling methods from different files. I also have just basic functions in the main file. A large number of them, unrelated to each other. Should i keep these in the same file or should i be placing them into a function file (functions.py).

Also should my main file have a main method or something? At the moment I just have code listed in lines.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please post the code you have so far

Comment: Your main file should have main method and it should be calling the other methods. Divide your file into sub-modules and functions and then call them accordingly. The functions that are not related directly to the main method, you can create different python files for it and call in your main file using import.

Comment: Ok. So a main method containing all my main program work along with calling in methods etc. Add the functions to a seperate file and call them within the main method too....